# Meaning of a sentence. The "could" in this sentence confuses me and my friends

Tags: meaning, grammar, syntactic-analysis

(Due to protectionist measures)Domestic sellers don't have an incentive to enhance efficiency and lower their prices, and under such conditions, *consumers eventually pay more for products and services they could receive from foreign competitors*.

Which one does it mean?

**a)** Consumers are now paying more for domestically-made products. But they could've bought them more cheaply from foreign companies if there were no protectionist measures.

or

**b)** Consumers are now buying the more expensive, foreign-made products.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no mention of preferring foreign products. Also, the protected products are not necessarily the same, only similar.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yeah, I made a mistake here. Let me re-phrase it: Consumers are now buying foreign products, which cost more.

Comment: It _may contain_ "subjunctive mood"? It's not submerged in the sentence, like a shark waiting for the unwary writer. I must say this is an unusual grammatical metaphor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

... consumers eventually pay more for products and services **that** they [otherwise] **would be able to** <s>receive</s> *obtain* from foreign competitors *[at a lower price] [if they made the effort to find foreign sellers]*.

The could is part of a conditional construction.